# expl3 / set length to average charwidth

Tags: macros, expl3, lengths, dimensions, function

I have a function that calculates the average character width. The function calculates the width as expected, but I can't use it in setlength.
I've tried around and tried solutions I've googled, but I can't get it to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{expl3} 
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c_typo_alphabet_tl {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\cs_new:Npn \typo_avg_charwidth:n #1 {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 \c_typo_alphabet_tl }
    \dim_eval:n { \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } / \tl_count:N \c_typo_alphabet_tl } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\typo_avg_charwidth:n {} % works, but only with braces!!
\par
\typo_avg_charwidth:n  {\textit} % works
\newlength{\charwidth}
\setlength{\charwidth}{\typo_avg_charwidth:n {} }  % error: missing number
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The most persistent error I receive is `! Missing number, treated as zero.`

```
\cs_show:N \typo_avg_charwidth:n
```

produces

```
> \typo_avg_charwidth:n=\long macro:#1->\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
{#1\c_typo_alphabet_tl }\dim_eval:n {\dim_eval:n {\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box
}/\tl_count:N \c_typo_alphabet_tl }.
<recently read> }
 
l.23 \cs_show:N \typo_avg_charwidth:n
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you need something that exands to a length so can not do assignments

Comment: what do you intend `#1` to be? `\typo_avg_charwidth:n {xyz}` does a rather odd calculation/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess formatting stuff like `\bfseries`...

Comment: Yes, it was intended to set a new font or \bfseries

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using your macro in an assignment you can do your box assignment, and then use that inside an assignment. That requires your macro to have a different syntax, but allows what you're intending to do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c_alexber_typo_alphabet_tl {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \alexber_set_avg_wd:Nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #2 \c_alexber_typo_alphabet_tl }
      \exp_args:NNNe
    \group_end:
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } / 26 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\settoavgwd{O{} m} { \alexber_set_avg_wd:Nn #2 {#1} }
\exp_args_generate:n {NNe}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength\charwidth

\begin{document}

\settoavgwd\charwidth
\the\charwidth

\settoavgwd[\bfseries]\charwidth
\the\charwidth

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does it need the nested groups?

Comment: Just to not leak any change to `\l_tmpa_box`, you could also use a private box and drop the group.

Comment: You have used \cs_new_protected:Npn. Does this mean that my problem is the expandable function?
I am trying to understand the problem and learn from it.

Comment: @alexBer yes, any assignments (e.g., box assignments) aren't expandable and should be used inside a `protected` macro.

Answer (score 3):

What we can do in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]
\typosize[12/14.4]

\def\settoavgwd#1{\tmpdim=0pt
   \foreach abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \do {\setbox0=\hbox{##1}\advance\tmpdim by\wd0}
   \divide\tmpdim by26
   \global #1=\tmpdim
}

\newdimen\charwidth

\settoavgwd\charwidth
\the\charwidth  % result: 5.74014pt

{\bf \settoavgwd\charwidth}
\the\charwidth  % result: 6.60599pt

\bye
```